# Flexible relationships in puppet?

Tags: puppet

### The setup

For the sake of this example, let's assume that I have two classes; `php` and `apache`.

- `php` can exist alone, because some machines (like CI/CD build slaves) only run `php` in CLI mode.
- One of `php`'s tasks is to manage `php.ini` files for various Linux distributions and use cases.
- `apache` can exist alone, because not every web deployment runs on `php`.
- One of `apache`'s tasks is to manage the `apache2` Service for various Linux distributions.

### The issue:

In use cases where both `php` and `apache` are provisioned on a node, a changed `php.ini` should result in a restart of the `apache2` Service, because `mod_php` would not pick up the change in the file otherwise.

So, following the documentation on [Relationships and Ordering](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html), I would have two choices in implementing this:

- `notify` the `apache2` Service from a `php.ini`File
- `subscribe` to a `php.ini`File from the `apache2` Service

This works fine when both Classes are included in a node manifest, but in situations where only one of them is included, it would yield an invalid relationship, like:

`Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid relationship: Service[apache] { subscribe => File[php.ini] }, because File[php.ini] doesn't seem to be in the catalog`

### The question

What kind of patterns or solutions exist to implement this type of 'flexible' relationships in Puppet? Something where you could `notify` or `subscribe` to objects that are not guaranteed to exist in the catalog (Like how `include` works for defining a Class multiple times)?

So far I've come up with two solutions that *could* work, but are both unfit (in my opinion):

- By using `if tagged('php') { } else { }` (or `if defined(Class['php']) { } else { }` for that matter) I could include an `apache` Service object twice that `subscribe`s to `php.ini` when it is included in the catalog, and doesn't when it's not. This does however create a lot of duplicate code and it contradicts the loose coupling / high cohesion principle.
- By using [parameterized classes](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#class-parameters-and-variables) I could pass knowledge about one to the other Class, changing it's behaviour based on the option provided. This does remove `include` flexibility/resilience however and you'd still need an `if {} else {}` in your class to implement the option, resulting in the same cons as the option above.

So, is there anything 'less hacky' around that I don't know about?

Comment: Surely you'd always have the apache2 service included on a node with a php.ini? Unless you have nodes which run php without a web frontend. In those cases, you could define php.ini twice with different names and different notify clauses.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: Although the question was meant in a more generic way instead of focussing on the specific example provided: Yes, I have nodes that run PHP without Apache. CI/CD build slaves for example (as mentioned in the question). And more specific issues: On RedHat nodes, CLI and Apache PHP use the *same* php.ini file. On Ubuntu for instance, they are separate. To account for the existance of Apache while ensuring  these `php.ini`'s would greatly increase the clutter that's already there and reduce Class independence (increasing tight coupling).

Comment: To go further off question then, IMHO Puppet's dependency-graph and DSL is its Achilles Heel. It's very powerful but becomes brittle to maintain after a while, especially as there's a million different syntax variations to achieve the same thing. A lack of simple externalised configuration with interpolation (so not Hiera) means that dealing with multiple environments leads to lots of config replication and clutter. For me, Ansible was a better fit </two pence>

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Hiera is simple, external, ánd has interpolation: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/variables.html, so that's not an argument. But yes, Ansible or Saltstack might be better solutions for various use cases. I've tried both, but with will remain with Puppet for the forseeable future for various reasons. (One of which is having a considerably large number of nodes running on a rather large puppet code base ;))

Comment: Interpolation only works on variables defined outside of Hiera or by using the lookup function to recursively lookup a value - fiddly at best and error prone at worst. E.g. `wordpress::database_server: "%{hiera('instances::mysql::public_hostname')}"`. Any way, like you say you've got an a mature install already and I've got way off point. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of patterns or solutions exist to implement this type of 'flexible' relationships in Puppet? Something where you could notify or subscribe to objects that are not guaranteed to exist in the catalog (Like how include works for defining a Class multiple times)?

It's probably best to use the Roles & Profiles pattern, and have a separate profile for Apache alone and Apache + PHP, with the latter (only) setting the relationship you want.  Then you know *why* the relationship exists for a given node (or should), and where it's needed you ensure that both components are declared.  For nodes that don't want Apache, you assign PHP via an unrelated profile.

Comment: That won't work, because it's invalid. See https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_collectors.html#syntax , specifically `The resource type, capitalized. This cannot be Class, and there is no way to collect classes.` . I've read the manual for both virtual resources and resource collectors a couple of times, and I use them both on other occasions, but for this particular problem I still fail to see how they would help solve the issue. I do use a Roles & Profiles pattern, but your suggestion would require me to have logic in the role, or have separate (or parameterized) classes

Comment: Ah, yes. I'm beginning to understand how this might work. https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#syntax-chaining-arrows combined with a resource collector might result in something like `File <| tag == 'trigger-apache' |> ~> Service['apache2']`. One set for each viable resource type unfortunately, but still more elegant than the other options. Trying if this works now..

Comment: Well, darn.  No, Class collectors won't work.  As for logic in your role classes, though, (1) it is expected for roles to have logic for choosing the right profiles, but (2) if your roles require logic for this particular case then they are probably defined too broadly.

Comment: In particular, suppose you had a machine on which you wanted PHP for non-web purposes, but also apache (without PHP support).  You can't distinguish that case based on the presence or absence of resources belonging to the two components.

Comment: It turns out your initial answer works like a charm! I've implemented a tag: `tag => ['trigger-apache'],` across multiple modules to each resource that requires a restart, and added http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481891/flexible-relationships-in-puppet?noredirect=1#comment49048010_30483583 to the apache module, which works flawlessly. If you edit your answer to reflect this I'll accept it. Or I can answer my own question and credit you there. Take your pick ;)